# Efficiently constrain values between -180 and 180

Tags: numpy

I have a user input which is a vector of longitudes (it can also be just a single number). This can be any number (I have no control over it). I need the longitudes cast into to the range -180 to 180 before passing them on to a C extension, e.g. 190 degrees should become -170 degrees (no clipping). What is the most efficient way to do this calculation in numpy?

Comment: Are you wanting to [`clip`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html)?

Comment: No, I want e.g. 190 degrees to be transformed to -170 degrees. A rotation, in other words. I've added a clarification to the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
angle_desired = ((angle + 180) % 360) - 180
```

% is the mod operator

Comment: Thanks! For the record, this was more than 3x faster than [Charlie's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32844931/2978652).

Answer (score 0):

Numpy's modulus operator and np.choose should do fine.

```
x=np.array([50,500,-190,60,390,270,181,-179,180,-180,179])
y=np.mod(x,360)
print y
z=np.choose(y<180,[y-360,y])
print z


[ 50 140 170  60  30 270 181 181 180 180 179]
[  50  140  170   60   30  -90 -179 -179 -180 -180  179]
```